# Identifying the signal picked up at 363mhz with sdr++. It is from Burmese military's communication. I want to know what it is and how to decode it

Tags: software-defined-radio, signal-identification, military-surplus

[image][image: Burmese Junta' communication signal]

As shown in the picture, I want to identify the signal and how can I decode it, please.
Here is the link to audio.wav file:
https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZRoY5VZggSdx8NPqKp3hAOaphcsKVVCqrik

Comment: This is more or less answered in previous Q&A if you search "identify signal": https://ham.stackexchange.com/search?q=identify+signal -- The usual advice is to visit the Signal Identification Wiki as a start: https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Signal_Identification_Guide (Maybe do a little research there and maybe you could self-answer back here.)

Comment: Also, make sure you aren't breaking the law where you live. Some places have strict laws about whether receivers can be used at all to listen to some traffic.

Comment: I live in Yangon(Rangoon) Myanmar(Burma), Military staged a coup and I'm against it.So I don't care the law they post. I used rtl-sdr to intercept  all their communication and I can't do anything to this one.

Comment: Amateur radio (except for "special" circumstances) and using receivers to listen to anything other than state radio is illegal in Myanmar. You can do what you want, but bear in mind that the state can visit SE sites as well, and possibly monitor your activity here.

Answer (score 1):

It *almost* looks like over-the-horizon (OTH) RADAR of some kind, but the fact that it is at ~363MHz (and those two peaks) is an argument otherwise.

The pauses do not seem to have timer-like regularity, so it *probably* isn't a synchronous digital mode.

My guess is that this is encoded and (probably) encrypted voice (or voice+data) communications for coordinating aircraft. Perhaps double-sideband suppressed carrier. With both sidebands and a nice wide bandwidth the receivers can be made a little simpler (relatively), and voice communications will be fairly resilient to noise.

There isn't a lot of variation in the amplitude, though, which leads me to believe that it isn't *only* some sort of aircraft AM. That being said, it might just be very compressed and expanded.

More research would be necessary. It might be nice to see the spectra view widened so we can see more details. And if there is a recognizable sound to the signal this can really help identify it. My guesses above imply you should be able to hear modulated tones of some kind if you demodulate this as AM. If you capture the audio you might be able to compare it with examples on the [Military Signal Wiki](https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Category:Military).

Decoding this traffic will probably be quite difficult if my assumptions are correct. If this is being generated by military spec SDR and encrypted you will have to be a pretty good cryptographer and/or have access to some special hardware.

There are apps like "SigDigger" that might assist in identifying encoding.

Comment: Here is the link: https://soundcloud.com/mg-gyi-120829167/control/s-In2wBjbP2im?utm_source=clipboard&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=social_sharing
Yes, I think it is the encrypted voice or/and data communication. I previously listened to that frequency and alert their command to some on fb'group to escape them.They noticed and changed it to that mode.

Comment: @MaungMaungGyi I don't think Soundcloud allows downloads (or maybe you need to create an account, which I'm certainly not going to do) and anyone who may get interested enough to try to figure out the encoding will want the audio file. Perhaps put a link to the audio file in the body of your question as a downloadable link of some sort?

Comment: That being said, this sounds like some kind of FSK or PSK modulation -- no surprises there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.